# Can I specify a set of Django user groups to be exclusive of each other?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django app that uses the stock User and Group models. I have two groups, group A and group B. I would like to prevent any user from being in both group A and group B, being in just one group or the other is fine. what is the best way to go about this? I was looking into model validation but I would like to do this without modifying or sub classing the stock User model. It would even be enough for me to be able to check and make sure that this wasnt being set on the django admin edit user page.